# python pattern matching to match exception

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to do a pattern match as follows to identify error rows

1234:20561 -- should not match

1234:3456778:hello --  should match

2345:3455667:      -- should match

no data             --should match

I was trying to use this `re.match('[0-9*:?0-9*:a-z]', string)` but can't get it to work.

How would I do this?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to use `re.match` with the following regex:

```
^(?:[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[a-z]*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uAsaLJ/2) (with `re.match`, the `^` is optional).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string (`re.match` anchors the pattern at the string start, then it may be omitted)
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group

  - `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
  - `:` - a colon
  - `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
  - `:`  - a colon
  - `[a-z]*` - 0+ ASCII letters (lowercase)
- `)?`  - the end of the non-capturing group, `?` quantifier makes it match 1 or 0 times (making it optional)
- `$` - end of string.

[Python demo](http://ideone.com/0jIPAk):

```
import re
ss = [ '1234:20561', '1234:3456778:hello', '2345:3455667:', '']
rx = re.compile(r'^(?:[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[a-z]*)?$')
for s in ss:
    if rx.match(s):
        print("{} matched.".format(s))
```

Output:

```
1234:3456778:hello matched.
2345:3455667: matched.
 matched.
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the first string to *not* match. And I think that requires changing your pattern to just: `r'^[0-9]*(?::[0-9]+)?(?::[a-z]*)$'`

Comment: @bernie: Yeah, it is a bad idea to answer questions at 2 AM :) Fixed.

Comment: WiktorStribiżew and bernie, thank you both. The changes that bernie suggested would provide the complete solution but Wiktor's solution is correct except for the first match and I have marked it as the correct one. Thank you Wiktor for also for explaining the flags in the details section. A lot of and books explain it generically but it's always useful to see how the expression was put together.  Greatly appreciate both of your responses

Comment: @ashu138: If you found it helpful, please consider also upvoting the answer since you got 15 rep points and have the [upvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) privilege now.